# Business Central 365 DtdProcessing prohibited. Where to set to alllow? (XmlReaderSettings)

Tags: dynamics-business-central

writing here to get help with Business Central 365 (on cloud) with **System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read** and DtdProcessing.

-> Firstly, when I log in to BC account and try to go to Business Central instance I'am getting this -> img [Error just after switching to instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHoJ1.png)

Don't know what could execute this error and how to fix it. It's happening due to wrong changes in custom extension or it's an internal BC365 error?

Where to set it in BC365, is it necessary to include into custom extension?

regards,
Jacob

Comment: It's unclear from your description if this is caused by your own extension or is this is just some client error. However .NET interop is not allowed in BC Online. You need to use one of the wrappers like codeunit 3013 DotNet_XmlDocument or codeunit 6224 "XML DOM Management".

Comment: Please provide an examples, that causes this error.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late answer. The problem was fixed. It was caused by an another external extension which was added as dependent in our ext. Happend due to the update from v14 to v15.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer. The problem was fixed. It was caused by an another external extension which was added as dependent in our ext. Happend due to the update from v14 to v15.

The external extension had a deleted / verbose fields.